# Nested document query MongoDB C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I have below person document

```
{
name:"John",
address:[
{
street:"1 abc",
city:"delhi"
},
{
street:"1 xyz",
city:"mumbai"
},
]
}
```

I have to fetch all person who's belongs to cites delhi and mumbai

I have written query using MongoDB C# 2.4 driver

```
string[] cities = new string[] { "delhi", "mumbai" };
var cityFilter =Builders<Person>.Filter.Eq("address.city",cities); 
   var person = database.GetCollection<Person>("Person").Find(cityFilter).ToList();
```

Query executes without exception but did not get any result.

Comment: You probably mean [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) or [`$all`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/). I depends on whether you mean "either" or "both" respectively.

Comment: I mean all, but it throws exception when i called All System.InvalidOperationException: The serializer for field "address.city '' must implement IBsonArraySerializer and provide item serialization info.

Comment: Then why does your question not mention any exception and the actual message or show any attempt at using `All`? Perhaps you should be adding this information to your question.

Comment: As per your comment I used All method which throws exception it was not the case with my query written in the question

Comment: I see no such code in your question. Which is where you need to be showing it. We cannot just run and look over your shoulder at your desk. Unless you show it here then we don't know exactly what you did.

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution:

```
var cityFilter = Builders<Person>.Filter.ElemMatch(y => y.addresses, x => cities.Contains(x.city));
```

Comment: Thanks @BOR4 I tried this but it gives OR result meaning person who has either delhi or mumbai. I want person with delhi and mumbai.

Comment: Ohh i didn't understand you correctly. I will fix it and post update.